# Extracting a string / characters between two known string / set of characters

Tags: regex, hadoop, substring, toad

I want to grab a string (name of a server) between two known strings (“Hostname: ” and “Host Alias:”) from a Column (named = description)

Sample data is

> we received the alert for the Service:xxxxx-iosdoh_free.USERSHostname: pugsxxxxdsbudlp01.eeeHost Alias: 894.aa

My Query with regex: (which is bringing blank value)

```
select regexp_extract(description, 'regex (?<=Hostname:).*?(?=Host Alias:), 1)', 
from tableA 
where number = '554';
```

My Query with Substring: (which is bringing blank value)

```
select substring(description, (locate('Hostname: ', description) + 8), (locate('Host Alias:', description) - 1) - (locate('Hostname: ', description) + 8)) as 'Server_Name'
from tableA 
where number = '554';
```

If I run the query to search between ‘We’ and ‘alert’ for string = We received alert...., then I do find ‘received’ in results because ‘We’ and ‘alert’ have spaces before and after them and is considered as a word.

How can I search with strings (no words) or if you have any better way to accomplish my task, it would be helpful.

Comment: What is the language/environment?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The database is hadoop. I m using 'Toad for Hadoop' and also trying Visual Studio 2010 with hortonworks hive drivers and also trying HUE (web portal)

Comment: Ok, should you really add `regex` word? Try `select regexp_extract(description, '(?<=Hostname:).*?(?=Host Alias:), 1)', `

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I tried removing regex but still, I am getting blank value, i also tried placing ' before comma before 1.
select regexp_extract(description, '(?<=Hostname:).*?(?=Host Alias:)', 1) but same result